# Use NSUserDefaults to change bundle display name?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, plist, nsuserdefaults

is it possible to use NSUserDefaults to store a Boolean value, and if this value is equal to "YES", then to change the BUNDLE DISPLAY NAME? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can’t change the BUNDLE DISPLAY NAME from within your app.  You must manually change the plist yourself.

Comment: Oh well, I was hoping this was possible. I want to bundle a lite and full version together, and if the user completes an in app purchase, it unlocks the content and takes "Free" out of the bundle display name. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Unfortunately Apple doesn't play nicely with these types of things :(.  They don't like having these upgrades be in-app purchases.